# Why can we neglect the beta term in the Callan-Symanzik equation of scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

In Peskin p413, He writes

> In any renormalizable massless scalar field theory, the two-point Green's function has the generic form $$
> \begin{aligned}
> G^{(2)}(p) &= \longrightarrow+(\text { loop diagrams })+\longrightarrow \otimes-\cdots \\
> &=\frac{i}{p^{2}}+\frac{i}{p^{2}}\left(A \log \frac{\Lambda^{2}}{-p^{2}}+\text { finite }\right)+\frac{i}{p^{2}}\left(i p^{2} \delta_{Z}\right) \frac{i}{p^{2}}+\cdots
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> The $M$ dependence of this expression, to lowest order, comes entirely from the counterterm $\delta_{Z}$. Applying the Callan-Symanzik equation to $G^{(2)}(p)$, and neglecting the $\beta$ term (which is always smaller by at least one power of the coupling constant), we find
> $$
> -\frac{i}{p^{2}} M \frac{\partial}{\partial M} \delta_{Z}+2 \gamma \frac{i}{p^{2}}=0
> $$

now comes to my question

In the $\lambda \phi^4$ theory, we know that the $\beta$ term, defined by
$$
\beta \equiv \frac{M}{\delta M} \delta \lambda
$$
is proportional to $\lambda^2$, so we can neglect this term in the Callan-Symanzik equation as higher order correction. But why can we neglect it in "any renormalizable massless scalar field theory" in general?

Comment: The section below Peskin & Schroeder's Equation (12.26), discussing the relation between the mass dimension of an operator and its beta function at tree-level in massless scalar field theory, shows you that operators with zero mass dimension are marginal at tree-level. But having zero mass dimension is also the condition for the interaction being perturbatively renormalizable.